# How do you refer to a contract own address inside it?

Tags: solidity, contract-design

I am attempting to use 2 contracts together, and I need my 2nd contract to pass his own address to the first contract.

Is there an easy way to do this? Like `this.address`?

Or should I update my contract own address into a variable?

Answer (score 108, accepted):

#### Solidity v5 Update

As of Solidity v5, `this` become deprecated. You now have to use `address(this)`.

#### Solidity v4 and older

[Get contract address in Solidity](http://solidity.readthedocs.org/en/latest/frequently-asked-questions.html#get-contract-address-in-solidity)

> Short answer: The global variable `this` is the contract address.

Long answer: `this` is a variable representing the current contract. Its type is the type of the contract. Since any contract type basically inherits from the address type, this is always convertible to address and in this case contains its own address.

Answer (score 38):

I tried `this` and `this.address` but found the following works:

```
function transferTo(address receiver, uint amount) {
    if (   amount == 0
        || receiver == address(this) )
        return;
```

Comment: Thank you, I was stuck because of this issue from a couple of hours. You trick helped a lot.

Comment: What is the difference between `address(this)` and just `this` ?

Comment: `this` is a deprecated way to get the address of the contract. As of Solidity 0.4.24 at least, `address(this)` is the only way that works.

Comment: Yep used address(this) going forward.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for an assembly (yul) answer:

```
contract ContractAddress {

    address public disAddress;

    constructor() public {
        assembly {
            sstore(disAddress_slot, address)
        }
    }
}
```

Notice the `address` on the 7th line? That refers to the contract's own address. Test it yourself in [Remix](http://remix.ethereum.org).