# token.balanceOf causing error in solidity

Tags: solidity

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.6;
import "./newERC20.sol";
contract TokenTimelock {

  newERC20 token;
  address beneficiary;
  uint releaseTime;


  function timelock(newERC20 _token, address _beneficiary, uint _releaseTime) public {
    require(_releaseTime > now);
    token = _token;
    beneficiary = _beneficiary;
    releaseTime = _releaseTime;
  }
  function claim() public {
    require(msg.sender == beneficiary);
    require(now >= releaseTime);

    uint amount = token.balanceOf(this);
    // what the purpose of using "uint amount" here, this amount produces an error

    require(amount > 0);

    token.transfer(beneficiary, amount);
  }
}
```

Or can you share more ways to lock certain amount of tokens and release on a specific time.

Comment: `balanceOf` is expecting an address not the amount in `uint`

Comment: ok,  if i put 'token.balanceOf(this)' it produces error again, when i change compiler version to 0.4 and 0.5 the error become silent but as i move to 0.6 it pop up again

Comment: Use functions supported in the solidity version you are using

Comment: right, we are using `balanceOf` property to find token balance?

Comment: `balanceOf ` can be used to find the token balance and `address(this).balance` to get ETH balance

Comment: i can't find the reason behind this, it is still showing that error while i'm applying all the possible methods.

Comment: ok @niksmac can you tell me why to use `newERC20`, this is the ERC20 interface, and if i not import it in this code, so the code will executed properly?

Comment: Regardless of what you're hoping to achieve with `uint amount = token.balanceOf(amount)`, it is incorrect by any programming standard (Solidity or other), as you are attempting to use the variable `amount` while declaring it!

Comment: try using: address(this) refer : https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2806/how-do-you-refer-to-a-contract-own-address-inside-it

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of what you're hoping to achieve with:

```
uint amount = token.balanceOf(amount);
// what the purpose of using "uint amount" here, this amount produces an error
```

It is incorrect by any programming standard (Solidity or other).

You are attempting to use the `amount` variable while declaring it.

Comment: yeah, i know it is incorrect, i correct it to `uint amount = token.balanceOf(this)` but still having error, when putting `(msg.sender)` it is correct.

Comment: what's about variable `releaseTime` if i want to lock tokens for next 10 minutes what should i do. as i know to do the following:

1. first i need to send tokens from token contract to this timeLock contract.
2. second i will lock tokens in this timeLock contract with the desired address to which i want to send.
2. how i'll mention the `releaseTime = now + 600 seconds`? OR `releaseTime = block.timeStamp + 600 seconds`?


please provide guidence...

Comment: @sultan: Your question was about this statement, and I've answered it. If you have a different question then please post it separately.